# TouchSwipe 1.6: Disable mouse "drag" on desktop browsers

Tags: jquery, swipe, gesture

I'm using TouchSwipe 1.6 jQuery plugin on my private website and it's working on tablet/phone, but it's working too on desktop browsers. If you can hold the mouse button and gesture swipe, it's slide to the next image.

How can i disable this function?

**EDIT:**

I found the solution:

```
if(fingerCount == 0)
{
  alert("Desktop");
}else{ 
  alert("Tablet/Mobile");
}
```

Comment: This is not the best solution because I still can't select text anymore on desktop.

Answer (score 2):

You could detect touch devices and use TouchSwipe only for them. For example:

```
function isMobile() {
    try{ document.createEvent("TouchEvent"); return true; }
    catch(e){ return false; }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    if (isMobile() == true) {
        $('body').swipe( {
            swipeLeft: function () {
                // Your swipe left event handler
                console.log('swipe left');
            },
            swipeRight: function () {
                // Your swipe right event handler
                console.log('swipe right');
            },
            // Default is 75px, set to 0 for demo so any distance triggers swipe
            threshold: 75
        });
    }
}
```